# Linq or Lambda Expression for returning comma separated values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can I get a list of comma separated values, like so:

```
CategoryName-ProductName1,ProductName2,etc
```

This code returns Product names that are comma-separated, but at the begening of the series I want the category name to appear and the preceding product names:

```
var result = from Cats in Categories
    where Cats.Id == 39
    select new { 
        Products = Cats.Products, 
        Cats = Cats
    }.
    Products.
    Select(Products => Products.Name).
    Aggregate((Items, Item) => Items + "," + Item);
```

Comment: Don't learn magic words.  Go back and learn the basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
var result = from cat in Categories
             where cat.Id == 39
             select cat.Name + "-" + String.Join(",",
                 cat.Products.Select(product => product.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
string result = Categories.Where(y => y.Id == 39).
                Select(y => y.Name + String.Join(",", y.Products.Select(x => x.Name)));
```

I haven't tried it myself but it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Categories
    .Where(c => c.Id == 39)
    .Select(c => c.Name + "-" + c.Products.Select(p => p.Name).Aggregate((acc,p) => acc + "," + p))
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options here. My take would be to split it in two:

```
var cat = Categories.Where(cat => cat.Id == 39);
var result = string.Format("{0}-{1}",
                  cat.Name,
                  cat.Products.Aggregate((list, product) => list + "," + product.Name));
```